# Как найти остатки вредоносного кода?

Tags: php, drupal, keyword

ситуация следующая: сайт на друпал-7 и некоторое время назад его основная страница (только она одна!) стала отображаться в гугле иероглифами.
простым поиском grep по слову "googlebot" был найден вредоносный пхп-код типа japanese keyword, который сидел в файле bootstrap.inc (папка /www/includes в корне сайта, код был добавлен прямо в начало файла), он был удален, все нормально заработало, но через несколько дней опять выехало то же самое и теперь тот же самый код был добавлен в файл default.settings.php в пути /www/sites/default. он был удален и опять через день появился тот же код только уже в файле template.php стандартной темы оформления.
никаких новых файлов, папок и прочего не появляется, изменения касаются только какого-то одного файла, куда просто "самодобавляется" этот пхп-код.
пароли учёток админов сменены, пароль фтп тоже.
если используется дыра в каком-то стороннем модуле, то как его вычислить, кто подскажет? заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если он "самодобавляется" - значит вирус имеет право записи в файлы. Значит он уже в системе. Вычистите код и скопируйте локально, дампаните БД, и снесите ОС. Обновите cms. Затем всем PHP-исполняемым файлам отберите права записи файлов(на случай дыр в коде) - у пользователя, под которым выполняется PHP (например):

```
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs chown deployuser    
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs chmod 644
find . -iname "*.inc" | xargs chown deployuser  
find . -iname "*.inc" | xargs chmod 644
```

Затем [запретите в настройках PHP небезопасные функции](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions), с помощью которых можно SSH тунель прокинуть. Проанализируйте открытые порты:

```
netstat -lntu
```

Например порт mysql (3306) стоит закрывать с помощью штатного фаервола ОС, подробнее про анализ портов выходит за рамки вопроса.

И если известен конкретный вирус - о его природе проникновения тоже известно в интернете. Тем не менее общие рекомендации по безопасности (читай выше) - выполнять стоит, иначе голова будет постоянно болеть.  Может помочь антивирус, но не 100%.

P.S. Если бы ваш проект был добавлен в репозиторий - git: то такие проблемы было бы гораздо проще решать, по команде `git status` - вы бы видели все изменённые не вами файлы, а `git checkout *` возвращал бы все правки файлов до вашей версии кода.

**UPD**

Если же доступ к серверу не полный тогда всё весьма ограничено в плане безопасности: нужно найти по access логам странные запросы - и выявить место, через которое к вам встраивается код, закрыть его.

Как это сделать: первым делом перенести весь код в git-репу, и склониться в свой каталог проекта(гит то там должен быть на сервере! Не забудьте при этом правильно сделать .gitignore файл) - потом когда бот опять придёт, одной командой вы увидите файлы, которые он поменял. У этих файлов будет дата модификации. Теперь вы сможете увидеть по access логу - каким точно запросом к вам проникли (просмотрев запросы по логу секундой раньше даты модификации). Ну и в коде закрыть этот дырявый запрос! А так-же увидите IP-адрес бота - мало ли найдётся и сам злоумышленник.

Если нравится тот-же хостер: так сделайте у него ещё аккаунт, и на него всё перенесите. Но думаю дело не в хостере, а в том что бот запомнил что у вас дыра - и периодически посещает вас. Тем не менее - если хотите годную web-безопасность, нужен минимум VDS.

Comment: большое спасибо за Ваш ответ! ос снести не получится, так как сайт не на vds, а обычно...а в остальном уже и база копировалась, и ядро обновлялось, но всё равно эта дрянь откуда-то появляется.( причём ведь первый раз добавилось не в пхп-файл, а в inc. по этому вирусу много смотрел, пишут, что после удаления кода больше ничего нет, а у меня почему-то опять появляется.

Comment: не подскажете в связи с этим вопросом - нормально ли такое отображение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790251/с-css-что-то-не-так-или-все-в-порядке

Comment: а может это быть проблема на хостинге?

Comment: @dobronravov  тогда думаю вам поможет смена настройка прав на исполняемые файлы. Скорее всего это не вирус, а бот, который ищет уязвимости в cms для спама - это проблема частая, решаемая, нужно закрыть ему вход. Если информацию о нём не найти - то нужно анализировать access-логи запросов, чтобы понять - как проник. Второй вопрос - нормально, это параметр для сброса кеша стилей. На хостинге проблема врядли, тем не менее это не помешает помучать техподдержку хостинга, или заказать новый хост а старый снести..

Comment: большущее спасибо!
сегодня обнаружил, что в корне сайта появились три файла без расширения и 0 байт каждый. именуются "is_base64", "data" и "Create a file with base64 encoded data,". удалил. хостер помогать и делать что-либо вообще не хочет. а не подскажете пожалуйста подробнее, что именно сделают команды find . -iname "*.php" | xargs chown deployuser     и find . -iname "*.php" | xargs chmod 644?

Comment: @dobronravov незачто. Суть этих команд - на все php файлы сменить owner-a на некого юзера `deployuser` и только ему дать права на редактирование этих файлов. То есть в случае необходимости надо создать доп-юзера линукса - ему делегируются права обновления кода, у этого юзера не должно быть публичного пароля - зато надо разрешить заходить под ним через sudo ( чтоб работало `sudo -u  deployuser bash` ). Тогда например апач будет по прежднему работать через пользователя `www-data` - и `www-data` (то есть при выполнении PHP скриптов) не сможет никак менять php файлы.

Comment: большое спасибо, но проблема в том, что я не могу ни создать доп.юзера линукса, ни разрешить ему что-либо, ни даже выполнить команду из-под sudo - сайт не на выделенном серваке, а на общей площадке... это к хостеру обращаться надо тогда?

Comment: @dobronravov дополнил ответ.

Comment: большое спасибо ещё раз!