# с css что-то не так или все в порядке?

Tags: html, css, drupal

при просмотре исходного кода страницы (и результата просмотра http в гугл-консоли) заметил, что все ссылки заканчиваются странным образом, пример:

```html
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url("/sites/all/modules/calendar/css/calendar_multiday.css?p4pwom");
@import url("/modules/comment/comment.css?p4pwom");
@import url("/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date.css?p4pwom");
```

это p4pwom - это вообще нормально или нет? в другой день в конце всех импорт-урлов с css было приписано p47m1e.
cms Друпал 7.
помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это нормально, так задумано. После внесения изменений в стили css, друпал автоматически присваивает какое либо значение после вопросительного знака, чтобы браузер брал стили не из Кеша (в случае если были внесены изменения).

Comment: огромное спасибо!!! а то я уж боялся что это какой-то вредонос развлекается.

Comment: @dobronravov если ответ помог, отметьте его решением, поддержите автора ответа.

Comment: отметил, спасибо!